# Using simple_form, how do I make the url field to only accept the http://domainname.com format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

So my plan for the string that will be inputted by the user in the url field is to use it as the link address like:

```
<%= link_to "Visit Site", @surf_school.url %>
```

But the link will only work if the user uses the http://google.com format and not with www.google.com or google.com. So how do I make this field to only accept a url format that is http://. Or better yet, is there a way to make the www.google.com or google.com to work?

```
<%= simple_form_for @surf_school do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :url %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What about other domains than .com? Seems to me the best thing is just to have a text field without any validations.

Comment: oh yeah you're right! But if I don't have a validation, and when the user will start their url in the url input field with anything other than http://, it will be a broken link.

Comment: The link could always be broken in either case. If you really want to make sure you can do a curl call with some gem and make sure the url returns 200. You could also do that with old links occasionally and flag ones that are broken.

Comment: Also, I would prepend the url with http in case http or https is missing.

Comment: Can you show me how to prepend the url with http?

Comment: Here is one way to do it (not tested): `url = 'http://' + url unless url.include? 'http'`

Answer (score 1):

Anyone looking at this now: a great Ruby gem for dealing with URLs in Rails is [Domainatrix](https://github.com/pauldix/domainatrix).

You can leave your form as is, allowing users to put in variations of URLs (as most people will put in 'www.mydomain.com' or 'mydomain.com').

The link then works like this:

`<%= link_to "Visit Site", Domainatrix.parse(@surf_school.url).url %>`

which will ensure your link works as expected regardless of how the domain is stored in the DB.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 36 times... Just the name alone: "Domainatrix"... I am IN!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex fro validation :

```
domain_regex = /^((http|https):\/\/)[a-z0-9]*(\.?[a-z0-9]+)\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.)?$/ix
```

And in rails validation place it as in model :

```
validates :url, :presence => true,
                   :format    => {  :with => domain_regex  }
```

It also takes https also. Or else simple use http in place of (http/https) in regex

Comment: This rejects many valid urls (hyphens, any tld longer than 5 characters, any host name with more than 3 components, IPv6 or IPv4 addresses etc.)